# "Infinitely Small Quantity" in SDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

The [original question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3413660/solve-the-stochastic-differential-equation-dy-t-rdt-alpha-y-tdb-t-where/3414259#3414259) is

> Solve the stochastic differential equation $dY_t=rd_t+αY_tdB_t$
> where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion.

In [Theoretical's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3414259/1093275) answer,

> \begin{align*}
> \mathrm d(FY)_t &= F_t\,\mathrm d Y_t + Y_t\, \mathrm dF_t + \mathrm d [F,Y]_t \\
> &= r F_t\,\mathrm d t + \alpha F_t Y_t \,\mathrm d B_t +\alpha^2 F_t Y_t \,\mathrm dt -\alpha F_t Y_t\,\mathrm d B_t -\alpha^2 F_t Y_t \,\mathrm d t \\
> &=r F_t \,\mathrm dt.
> \end{align*}

how can we calculate $d[F,Y]_t$ in the second equation? I've done some search and find that it should be $o(\sqrt{(dF_t)^2+(dY_t)^2})$ in ODE but I have no idea about it in SDE.

Thanks a lot for answering.

Comment: In SDE that $d[F,Y]_t$ is also often written as $d\langle F,Y\rangle_t$ and is called quadratic covariation. Please google it, read Wikipedia, or any SDE book you like.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Kurt, I searched for related articles and found the quadratic variation can be calculated with $dF_t*dY_t$.[1]

Some common stochastic processes such as Brownian motion and Poisson processes are semimartingales.

[1] [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#It%C3%B4_processes:~:text=.-,Semimartingales,-%5Bedit%5D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#It%C3%B4_processes:%7E:text=.-,Semimartingales,-%5Bedit%5D)